# Repeat Method In While Loop

Tags: java, loops, methods

I cant seem to get my main method working as it should 100%. It is good but I need fix a looping problem.

My main goal was to get the program to repeat method pathCalc() once user enters any number >=1 and to end the program when user enters 0. However, when user enters >= 1 to repeat the program, program does repeat, but when it gets to the point to ask user if to repeat or exit again, and user enters 0 to exit, the program repeats method pathCalc() instead of exiting.

How do I get this to work after repeating method, so that the user enters >= 1 to repeat method or 0 to exit?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

      public class AssignmentArrays{
         static int[] data = new int [6];

            public static void getIDs(){

               Scanner seg = new Scanner(System.in);

               int[] data = new int [6];
               data[0] = 0;
               data[1] = 0;
               data[2] = 0;
               data[3] = 0;
               data[4] = 0;
               data[5] = 0;

              /* Segment values */



               System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 0:");
               data[0] = seg.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 1:");
               data[1] = seg.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 2::");
               data[2] = seg.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 3:");
               data[3] = seg.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 4:");
               data[4] = seg.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 5:");
               data[5] = seg.nextInt();

   }

     public static void pathCalc(){     

     /* Path inputs */

     Scanner node1 = new Scanner(System.in);


     int pathCost;

     System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 0 of path:");
     int node1value = node1.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 1 of path:");
     int node2value = node1.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 2 of path:");
     int node3value = node1.nextInt();

     /* Path cost calculation */

     pathCost = data[node1value] + data[node2value] + data[node3value];
     System.out.println("The cost of the trip is: $" + pathCost);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
      getIDs();
      pathCalc();
      System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or any other number"+
                                        " to evaluate another path:");
         int choice;
         choice = end.nextInt();

         while(choice != 0){
         getIDs();
         pathCalc();
         System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or any other number"+
                                        " to evaluate another path:");
         choice = end.nextInt();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the `choice` tow times within the while loop. Move one instance out as below:

```
    getIDs();
    pathCalc();
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or any other number"+
                                            " to evaluate another path:");
    int choice = end.nextInt();
    while(choice != 0){
         //getIDs();
         pathCalc();
         System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or any other number"+
                                            " to evaluate another path:");
         choice = end.nextInt();
    }
```

Also, there is not need of extra flag. you an use `choice` itself in the condition as mentioned above.

**Your while loop will not start, if user enter `0` in the beginning; and the loop will terminate automatically when user enters `0` afterwards.**

**EDIT:** Updated program.

```
public class AssignmentArrays {
    static int[] data = new int[6];
    static Scanner seg;

    public static void getIDs() {
        int[] data = new int[6];
        data[0] = 0;
        data[1] = 0;
        data[2] = 0;
        data[3] = 0;
        data[4] = 0;
        data[5] = 0;

        /* Segment values */

        System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 0:");
        data[0] = seg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 1:");
        data[1] = seg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 2::");
        data[2] = seg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 3:");
        data[3] = seg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 4:");
        data[4] = seg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 5:");
        data[5] = seg.nextInt();

    }

    public static void pathCalc() {
        int pathCost;

        System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 0 of path:");
        int node1value = seg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 1 of path:");
        int node2value = seg.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 2 of path:");
        int node3value = seg.nextInt();

        /* Path cost calculation */

        pathCost = data[node1value] + data[node2value] + data[node3value];
        System.out.println("The cost of the trip is: $" + pathCost);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        seg = new Scanner(System.in);
        getIDs();
        pathCalc();
        System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or any other number"
                + " to evaluate another path:");
        int choice;
        choice = seg.nextInt();

        while (choice != 0) {
            getIDs();
            pathCalc();
            System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or any other number"
                    + " to evaluate another path:");
            choice = seg.nextInt();
        }
        seg.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not achieve what I need to do. I have two methods which are executed before the main method. First the program needs to read user input to an array getIDs();, then the program ask user for 3 ids to calculate a price pathCalc(); User is then asked what he/she wants to do, calculate another path or exit. If >=1 is entered, pathCalc();. After this user is asked again if to pathCalc(); or exit.

Comment: @Kronos: I updated the answer. Hope it works as you expect, otherwise, please share your `pathCalc();` and `getIDs();` method summary, which will help me understand your question better.

Comment: I updated my question. I get two exceptions. Hopefully you better understand now.

Comment: @Kronos: I updated the answer with modified program. This seems to be working. Check and let me know, if you see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (choice == 0){ 
System.exit(0);
 }
```

to exit directly or make sure to check choice before entering the loop